# Does Nest use the MQTT protocol?

Tags: mqtt, nest-api

I have an existing home automation device using the open standard MQTT protocol. Will it be compatible with Nest? How to connect them?

In my opinion, if the Internet of Things wants to gain traction, it should be interoperable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: Nest does not use the MQTT protocol out of the box, but there is a [**Nest-MQTT bridge**](https://github.com/neographikal/nest-mqtt-bridge) using Node.js and [Cyclon.js](https://cylonjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This would require a bridge daemon to run somewhere.

Comment: I mean that you would probably need to implement it.